# Replace everything except numbers in a string vb6

Tags: string, vb6, replace

well i did my research and seen a lot of posts about this but couldnt find a solution in **VB6**
so how can i do this in **VB6**?

lets say i got a string like:

" Once upon a time there was a little kid who wonders about going further than `1000` of miles away from home... "

i want to get only **numbers** "`1000`" in this string seperated from string and wanna replace the whole string but numbers should stand still.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way is to walk the string and copy numbers to a new one:

```
Function GetNumbers(Value As String) As String
Dim Index As Long
Dim Final As String

  For Index = 1 To Len(Value)
    If Mid(Value, Index, 1) Like "[0-9]" Then
      Final = Final & Mid(Value, Index, 1)
    End If
  Next

  GetNumbers = Final
End Function
```

The result:

```
?GetNumbers("abc12def345")
12345
```

This is inefficient with long strings when there are lots of numbers though.

Comment: A better or more current solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/3977549/4528239

Comment: @neosonne that's is a different language, c# instead of vb6

Comment: it isn't matter, the both languages are doing the same, only with different syntax:
`Function GetNumbers(val As String) As String
Return CType(val.Where(Function(c) Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray(), String)
End Function`

Comment: @neosonne that's not valid VB6 syntax. Note, VB6, not VB.net.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Deanna's answer:

```
Function GetNumbers(Value As String) As String
Dim Index As Long
Dim Digit As String
Dim Final As String
Dim Count As Long

  Count = 1
  GetNumbers = Space(Len(Value))
  For Index = 1 To Len(Value)
    Digit = Mid(Value, Index, 1)
    If Digit Like "[0-9]" Then
      Mid(GetNumbers, Count, 1) = Digit
      Count = Count + 1
    End If
  Next

  GetNumbers = Left(GetNumbers, Count - 1)
End Function
```

This function should be `O(n)`

```
?GetNumbers("abc12def345")
12345
```

Comment: And the more efficient version. I left that as an excercise for the reader as I'm lazy :p

Answer (score 0):

You may use regular expressions:

```
Dim NumExp As New RegExp

NumExp.Pattern = "\D"
NumExp.Global = True

strOutput = NumExp.Replace(strWhatToReplace, strReplaceWithWhat)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nStr = "abc12def345"
For X = 1 To Len(nStr)
    If IsNumeric(Mid(nStr, X, 1)) = True Then
        nNum = nNum & Mid(nStr, X, 1)
    End If
Next X


MsgBox nNum
```